# What libraries I can use for Anomaly detection in Time-series data in Python?

Tags: python, time-series, data-analysis, anomaly-detection

I am working with data that consists of two variables:

1. Date-Time (in 15minutes intervals)
2. Demand

With these variables, I need to build a model to train the data in detecting anomalies in the data. Currently, I am using Pandas but are there any other libraries that I might use?

Comment: Please show that you have done some research (ie googled a bit), before asking a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Python libraries [pyod](https://pyod.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), [pycaret](https://pycaret.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html), [fbprophet](https://pypi.org/project/fbprophet/), and scipy are good for automating anomaly detection.

There is a [good article](https://towardsdatascience.com/time-series-of-price-anomaly-detection-13586cd5ff46) on how to do a variety of anomaly detection exercises on a sample dataset from Expedia.  Although it isn't explained in the article, the author used the [Pandas](https://pypi.org/project/pandas/) library to load and analyze time series data.  This is a good article to make sure you better understand some of the capabilities of the library that you are already using for anomaly detection.

Another [good article](https://blog.floydhub.com/introduction-to-anomaly-detection-in-python/) uses Pandas for the time series data and uses additional libraries for anomaly detection analysis.  I found this article useful when starting out since it uses [Faker](https://pypi.org/project/Faker/) and [NumPy](https://pypi.org/project/numpy/#description) to create fake data, so it is easy to duplicate the tests in the article.

Answer (score 0):

There are more than a dozen now:

1. [PyOD](https://pyod.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) - the number one choice as it has over 30 algorithms both classic and deep learning models.
2. [Scikit-learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/outlier_detection.html) - has a great guide on both outlier detection and novelty detection and has five algorithms supported.
3. [alibi-detect](https://github.com/SeldonIO/alibi-detect) - offers outlier, adversial and drift detection methods. Has over 2k stars.

There are some classic statistical methods like MAD in `statsmodels` as well. You can also check out `PyNomaly`, `pyanomaly` but I don't know if they are well-maintained.